# Display field value of data type token_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
   "fullName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false,
            "similarity" : "boolean",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "terms" : {
                "type" : "token_count",
                "analyzer" : "standard"
              }
            }
          }
```

I want to display the value of terms field. When I do the following, I get the fullName but not the terms value

```
GET /_search
{"_source": ["fullName","fullName.terms"], 
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['fullName.terms'].value != 3,
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure that your token count is stored - [Here documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html#token-count-params)

You should modify your mapping :

```
"terms" : {
    "type" : "token_count",
    "analyzer" : "standard",
    "store": true
}
```

Then to retrive the value you need to explicitly ask for stored value in your query : ( [here documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) )

```
GET /_search
{
  "_source": [
    "fullName"
  ],
  "stored_fields": [
    "fullName.terms"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['fullName.terms'].value != 3",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am unclear on one thing, the check in the script part works, which means that the count is present somewhere. Can't we just not retrieve it in any way? Storing it like you said would be additional? If this is the only way, can the mapping be updated now without re-indexing?

Comment: 1/ doc['fullName.terms'] target the values indexed, but those values are not meant to be retrieved so the value is present but you cant see it without configuring the store to true ( check the head of the store documentation page for explanation ) 2/ Even if you can add the store true without reindexing ( never tried ) the term_count value will not be stored for previously indexed doc. So no, you have to reindex or use update_by_query.